# Subgroup Lattice of D14 - normal and centre

Tags: group-theory

I saw this question earlier on the forum and was wondering if my result to it was correct!

If D14 is the dihedral group acting on a heptagon, are the only subgroups in the lattice D14, < r> , < o> and e? Where o is rotation and r is reflection and < x> gives the group generated by x.

My thought process was that < o^n> would not be unique as it would generate exactly the some thing as < o> and everything else would generate the entire group so not be a subgroup. Is my thinking correct?

Am I also right in thinking the centre is just (e) and the normal subgroups are just D14, (e) and < o>.

Thanks =)

Comment: If you meant $r$ to run through all the reflections, then you've got it! If $r$ represents just one of the reflections, then you're missing some subgroups.

Comment: I had r as reflection in a line from a single corner to the opposite side. Wouldn't r^2 just give back the identity element so there is only one reflection?

Comment: There are $n$ reflections. $r$, $or$, $o^2r$, etc.

Comment: Note that the heptagon has 7 corners so there are 7 reflections in the lines that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You're right with the centre being *{e}* as this is true for all groups $D_n$ where n is odd.